# method is called only in debug mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, opc-ua

I'm trying to create a OPC UA client in unity. I need to read 2 data values from the server (alpha and beta) and use them in my game. the values should get updated in the game whenever they're changed in the server.

I tried this code but for some reason the updated values only get logged to unity's console when I'm debugging the game (if there's a breakpoint anywhere in the script).

```
using Opc.Ua;
using Opc.Ua.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Playables;

public class Global
{
    public static List<MonitoredItem> list = new List<MonitoredItem>();
    public static List<int> values = new List<int>();
}

public class trialx : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string endpointurl;

    void Start()
    {
        
        Debug.Log("Create a session");

        using (var session = Session.Create(config, new ConfiguredEndpoint(null, new EndpointDescription(endpointurl)), true, "", 60000, null, null).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
        {
           
            

            Debug.Log("Browse the server namespace.");
            ReferenceDescriptionCollection refs;
            byte[] cp;
            session.Browse(null, null, ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder, 0u, BrowseDirection.Forward, ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, true, (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method, out cp, out refs);


            Debug.Log("Create a subscription");
            var subscription = new Subscription(session.DefaultSubscription) { PublishingInterval = 1000, PublishingEnabled = true, KeepAliveCount = 5 };
            session.AddSubscription(subscription);
            subscription.Create();


            Debug.Log("Add monitored items to the subscription.");
            var m = new MonitoredItem(subscription.DefaultItem) { DisplayName = "alpha", StartNodeId = "ns=2;s=Alpha", SamplingInterval = 1000 };
            Global.list.Add(m);
            Global.list.Add(new MonitoredItem(subscription.DefaultItem) { DisplayName = "beta", StartNodeId = "ns=2;s=Beta", SamplingInterval = 1000 });
            foreach(var item in Global.list) { item.Notification += OnNotification; }
            subscription.AddItems(Global.list);
            subscription.ApplyChanges();


            Debug.Log("Read Values of Monitored items.");
            foreach (var item in Global.list)
            {
                var v = session.ReadValue(item.StartNodeId);
                int val = Convert.ToInt16(v.Value);
                Global.values.Add(val);
            }
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


        Global.list.ForEach(i => i.Notification += OnNotification);
        
        



    }

    private void OnNotification(MonitoredItem monitoredItem, MonitoredItemNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Log MonitoredItem Notification event

            
            MonitoredItemNotification notification = e.NotificationValue as MonitoredItemNotification;

           

            Debug.Log("Notification: " + notification.Message.SequenceNumber + " \" " + monitoredItem.ResolvedNodeId + " \" and Value = " + notification.Value);
            Debug.Log(monitoredItem.DisplayName + " = " + notification.Value);

            string value = Convert.ToString(notification.Value);
            var y = Global.list.FindIndex(x => x.DisplayName == monitoredItem.DisplayName);
            int val = Convert.ToInt16(value);
            Global.values[y] = val;

          

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("OnMonitoredItemNotification error: {0}", ex.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

More specifically, these lines

```
Debug.Log("Notification: " + notification.Message.SequenceNumber + " \" " + monitoredItem.ResolvedNodeId + " \" and Value = " + notification.Value);
            Debug.Log(monitoredItem.DisplayName + " = " + notification.Value);

            string value = Convert.ToString(notification.Value);
            var y = Global.list.FindIndex(x => x.DisplayName == monitoredItem.DisplayName);
            int val = Convert.ToInt16(value);
            Global.values[y] = val;
```

only gets executed when I'm debugging which makes me think that the OnNotification() event handler only gets called in debug mode and I can't figure out why.

I'm, using the UA.NetStandard library ( the nuget package OPCFoudation.NetStandard.OPC.UA.Client )

Comment: `Debug.Log` is indeed executed only in debug mode. But there is no reason the rest should not be executed. I's recommend replacing your logging logic if you need some in proper production release logging information.

Comment: You're just *assigning* the delegate on every iteration, not *executing it*. I thhink you should use `foreach(var l in l.Notification(whatever))`, assuming `MonitoredItenm.Notification` is some delegate.

Comment: @Pac0 I'm not talking about release mode. When I press play in Unity editor, these lines don't get executed unless I insert a breakpoint any where in the script and attach the debugger to unity.  Other Debug.Log statements work just fine

Comment: thanks for the clarification, in this case I don't have any idea of what's happening unfortunately